# ZF: how to call model from default module?

Tags: php, zend-framework, model, module

For example Admin_Model_Type called fine. But Default_Model_Type - doesn't.

I tried to call it without default and renamed class form Default_Model_Type to Model_Type. But it doesn't help.

I looked through lots of topics and everybody added path prefix to `application.ini`. Seems it is wrong way.

Is some idea how to do it without path prefix settings?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! It was nessecery to add defalt_bootstrap for default module. Now it works fine!